# Can I browse text backwards for a String in Visual C#?

Tags: c#, string, search

I have a Search function with them I can Search a string inside my richtextbox from the beginning of the text to the end. When I found the last accordance it start from begin.

Here the code:

```
       #region Search

      private void txtSearch_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        start = 0;
        end = 0;
    }     

    //Searchfield
    private void toolStripTextBoxSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }//end TextBoxSearch

    public int FindMyText(string txtToSearch, int searchStart, int searchEnd)
    {
        // Set the return value to -1 by default.
        int retVal = -1;

        // A valid starting index should be specified.
        if (searchStart >= 0)
        {
            // A valid ending index
            if (searchEnd > searchStart || searchEnd == -1)
            {
                // Find the position of search string in RichTextBox
                indexOfSearchText = richTextBox.Find(txtToSearch, searchStart, searchEnd, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
                // Determine whether the text was found in richTextBox1.
                if (indexOfSearchText != -1)
                {
                    // Return the index to the specified search text.
                    retVal = indexOfSearchText;
                }
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }//end FindMyText

    private void buttonSearch_left_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void buttonSearch_right_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int startindex = 0;

        if (txtSearch.Text.Length > 0)
        {
             startindex = FindMyText(txtSearch.Text, start, richTextBox.Text.Length);
        }
            // If string was not found report it
            if (startindex < 0 )
            {
                if (stringfoundflag==1)
                {
                startindex = FindMyText(txtSearch.Text, 0, richTextBox.Text.Length); //Start at Pos. 0
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Not found in Textfield", "Search", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }//end if 

             if (startindex >= 0)
            {
                stringfoundflag = 1;
            // Set the highlight color as red
            //richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
            // Find the end index. End Index = number of characters in textbox
            int endindex = txtSearch.Text.Length;
                // Highlight the search string
                richTextBox.Select(startindex, endindex);
                // mark the start position after the position of
                // last search string
                start = startindex + endindex;
        }
    }

    // Reset the richtextbox when user changes the search string
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        start = 0;
        indexOfSearchText = 0;
    }

    private void txtSearch_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtSearch.Text == "Search")
        {
            txtSearch.Text = "";
        }
    }

    private void txtSearch_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtSearch.Text == "")
        {
            txtSearch.Text = "Search";
        }
    }

    #endregion
```

I have two button one search right and one left, the right works like the description at the start.

Question:

Can I reverse the searchfunction from button right to left with my solution, or must I change the whole search function?

Example: Start at first accordance and jump than to the last accordance and then next-to-last and so on.

Comment: You only need to change the last parameter to [RichTextBoxFinds.Reverse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yab8wkhy(v=vs.110).aspx). See the remarks section.

Comment: Are you sure the tags on your question are OK? None of your code seems to be about asp.net or webforms

Comment: i have delete the tags that has add an editor. thx for your help rene i have found a solution

Comment: How about that? http://www.dotnetperls.com/lastindexof

Comment: I found a bug in the code so when you have used it show pls if you have the eventhandler KeyPress i fix it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem.

Code:

```
        public int FindMyTextleft(string txtToSearch, int searchStart, int searchEnd)
    {
        // Set the return value to -1 by default.
        int retVal = -1;

        // A valid starting index should be specified.
        if (searchStart >= 0)
        {
            // A valid ending index
            if (searchEnd > searchStart || searchEnd == -1)
            {
                // Find the position of search string in RichTextBox
                indexOfSearchText = richTextBox.Find(txtToSearch, searchStart, searchEnd, RichTextBoxFinds.Reverse);
                // Determine whether the text was found in richTextBox1.
                if (indexOfSearchText != -1)
                {
                    // Return the index to the specified search text.
                    retVal = indexOfSearchText;
                }
            }
        }//end FindMyTextleft
        return retVal;
    }//end FindMyText

    private void buttonSearch_left_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int startindex = 0;

        if (txtSearch.Text.Length > 0 & stringfoundflag == 1)
        {
            startindex = FindMyTextleft(txtSearch.Text, startindex, end);
        }

        else if (txtSearch.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            startindex = FindMyTextleft(txtSearch.Text, start, richTextBox.Text.Length);
        }
        // If string was not found report it
        if (startindex < 0)
        {
            if (stringfoundflag == 1)
            {
                startindex = FindMyTextleft(txtSearch.Text, 0, richTextBox.Text.Length); //Start at Pos. 0
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not found in Textfield", "Search", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }//end if 

        if (startindex >= 0)
        {
            stringfoundflag = 1;
            // Set the highlight color as red
            //richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
            // Find the end index. End Index = number of characters in textbox
            int endindex = txtSearch.Text.Length;
            // Highlight the search string
            richTextBox.Select(startindex, endindex);
            // mark the start position after the position of
            // last search string
            end = startindex;
        }
    }//buttonSearch_left_Click
```